# Accents Appear Next to Letter in Firefox

Tags: firefox, text, character-encoding, char

I'm currently working on a website and I'm having a problem with accents in Firefox. There are a few accented words where the accents appear next to the letter instead of above or below it.

Here's a picture of the issue:https://i.stack.imgur.com/zof0t.png

You can visit the website here: http://test.psidomusic.com/home/?lng=br

It looks fine on Chrome, Safari, and Opera. I've also tried changing the Character Encoding settings on Firefox from UTF-8 to Western (ISO-8859-1 and Western-1252), but it still doesn't output as it should. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the newest version of FireFox might help. I'm using 27 and if I copy/paste the text, the accents are placed correctly.

However, I see a far worse problem: the bottom half of each line is missing, as if there's a strip of paper covering it.

[image: screenshot]